# Spring boot, how do I hide or prevent from loading some properties of an entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an Account class which contains all the information like username email and password. I would like to use this class for giving me some properties like username or email to show on his/her profile page, but not the password because I know it's insecure to let this field going through http/https protocol even it's hashed. I tried to hide it using @Transient, but another class AccountPrincipal still needs this field to authenticate anyways. what's proper and secure way to do this?

This is how the information looks like if I try to get some account information via controller.

```
[
    {
        "accountId": 1,
        "userName": "pink",
        "nuggerPoint": null,
        "videos": [],
        "password": "$2a$10$jrL.YPkkvLN0fThW2e7Lne/J7ak0wb3XF4TyG.xNp9zcomuC1QHjG"
    },
    {
        "accountId": 2,
        "userName": "guy",
        "nuggerPoint": null,
        "videos": [],
        "password": "$2a$10$L2st0.RTpzeoCB72G4JG9eazZpistVxpj51UL2fVbjLxxbb6zKjaa"
    }
]
```

--

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long accountId;
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;

    public Account(String username, String password, Long nuggerpoint){
        this.userName = username;
        this.passWord = password;
        this.nuggerPoint = nuggerPoint;
    }
    public Long getAccountId(){
        return accountId;
    }
    public void setAccountId(Long accountId){
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }
    public String getUserName(){
        return this.userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return this.passWord;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.passWord = password;
    }
    // some other methods and properties
}
```

--

```
public class AccountPrincipal implements UserDetails {
    private Account account;
    public AccountPrincipal(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.account.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.account.getUserName();
    }
    //Some other methods..
}
```

--

Comment: You should use DTO for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Answer (score 2):

you can use `@JsonIgnore` annotation on your `public String getPassword()` method to ignore the field during serialization.

And use `@JsonProperty` annotation on your `public String setPassword(String password)` to enable deserialization when you want to set it.

More details here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called **DTO** Data Transfer Object. This will help you to map between the result from your entity and what you want to expose to users.